# parser for c++ headers to extract functions with standard linux tools?

Tags: c++, parsing, header

Is there something like this? I need to extract C++ functions from header files with all the parameters they use. It would be nice if i can use standard Linux programs

Comment: Can you give more information? Are you trying to transform the code? One common thing to do this for is generating interop with other languages - in that case www.swig.org is for you.

Comment: The only way to do this is to use a C++ parser of some sort. You can't do it with tools like (for instance) grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use understand 4 C++ which is a front end tool that browse your source code and generate metrics for your source code. It also has a powerful API that allows you to write your own static analysis tools. So far understand works on windows, and a bunch of other linux based OS's. Though I've only used the windows based API.
It is found at:

http://scitools.com/

Comment: FYI, I wrote a tool using this API that does something you want, and more: It dumps every significant function declaration and class definition in a header file out to a text file. Obviously