# parser for c++ headers to extract functions with standard linux tools?

Tags: c++, parsing, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [parser for c++ headers to extract functions with standard linux tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941363/parser-for-c-headers-to-extract-functions-with-standard-linux-tools)

is there something like this? need to extract c++ functions from header files with all the parameters they use. would be nice if i can use standard linux programms

Comment: Asking the same question multiple times is not considered acceptable behavior on this site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941363/parser-for-c-headers-to-extract-functions-with-standard-linux-tools

Comment: Thanks for the link hammer, I answered this yesterday, but thought somehow the answer was lost, so I answered this again. I think I'm done with this quesiton...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a program called ['understand 4 c++'](http://www.scitools.com). What it does is parse your program like a compiler. However instead of spitting out executable code, it just creates relationships that you can browse your source code (Like Intellisense in visual studio). 
However it is very powerful. The best and my favorite part is that it exposes a very powerful API that allows you to write your own static analysis tools.

So in essence, just dumping all function signatures in header files is a snap using this API.